# Compare and insert

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good day to all

I have 2 lists of data exported from the same company. Sheet 1 contains Product Description (Column a), Last Price (Column b) containing no values at the moment.

List 2 has more or less the same data with Description (Column a) and last price (column b) currently containing values.

I need to compare list 2 (Column a) to list 1 (Column a) to check that all the items reflect in sheet 1 (column a) then have the values of sheet 2 (column b) inserted into sheet 1 (column b) where sheet 2 (column a) matches sheet 1 (column a)

Please assist as I do not know much about MS Excel and this is a first for me.

Comment: Look into VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0):

First "to compare list 2 (Column a) to list 1 (Column a) to check that all the items reflect in sheet 1" you can use the MATCH and ISNUMBER formulas. You can put this on the second row in column C on Sheet 1 (so cell C2) and it would go something like this.

**=ISNUMBER(MATCH('Sheet 1'!$A2,'Sheet 2'!$A:$A,0))**

The ISNUMBER formula will tell you if whatever you have inside the brackets **is a number** or not, by returning TRUE or FALSE. The MATCH formula will give you a number if the product in cell A2 on sheet 1 **matches** a product anywhere in Column A on Sheet 2. The 0 tells the formula to match exactly what you have asked for. If there is not a match, then the MATCH formula will return an error (which is not a number) so ISNUMBER will give you FALSE.

You will need to copy this formula down to cover all the rows of products you have in Sheet 1 and you will have a column of TRUE or FALSE depending on if there is a match between the 2 columns.

I have assumed that the top row of your sheet has words like "Description" and "Last Price" in it and that you don't want to compare those which is why I said start in row 2.

Now you have a column that tells you if that product is in Sheet 2, you can use that to check if it is worth trying to find the last price.

So to "have the values of sheet 2 (column b) inserted into sheet 1 (column b) where sheet 2 (column a) matches sheet 1 (column a)" you can write the following formula in to cell B2 on sheet 1.

**=IF('Sheet 1'!$C2,INDEX('Sheet 2'!$B:$B,MATCH('Sheet 1'!$A2,'Sheet 2'!$A:$A,0)),"404 Product Not Found")**

First it uses the IF formula to check **if** we found a match in the first formula. Then if we did (so the first formula returned TRUE) we use the INDEX and MATCH functions to **match** which row the product is on Sheet 2 and then **index** the price from sheet 2 that is on the same row.

If the first formula did not find a match (so C2 is FALSE) then you will get "404 Product Not Found" instead of a price. You can change this to whatever is more helpful, or just leave it blank to get the word FALSE.